# I can't find my custom TextBox control in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm creating a custom WinForms TextBox control, like this:

```
class MyTest : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

When I build the project, I cannot see the control. Can anyone explain why not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i need to see hem in Toolbox ? no ?
or where ? and how to use it ?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116311/c-how-to-put-extended-winforms-control-on-toolbox

Answer (score 0):

you should add the control inside a project and place it on a form.   Just a usercontrol by itself you will not see when you build the project.

Comment: check this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yxtkx75%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The control should automatically be displayed and will show up under a tab with the project name.  You have to be within a designer view other than your control.  If that doesn't work you can right click on the toolbox and click Reset Toolbox.  Make sure you are rebuilding the entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the project containing the custom TextBox a class library.
If you however decide to keep it as a single UserControl file in the current project, you'll have to reference the control manually.