# How to add an extended control to the toolbox, when the control is in the same project?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, controls, toolbox

I have extended `DataGridView`. I want to add the new control to the toolbox without adding a reference to a different assembly (using the right-click option "Choose Items"). The control is in the same project of the form, and I do not want to separate them. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

**Edit:** This could not possibly a duplicate of a question about user controls if it's not a user control.

**Edit 2:** The code itself (it's a work in process. It's not finished):

```
class BindedDataGrid<T> : DataGridView
{
    public BindedDataGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(BindingValueAttribute)));

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            var column = new DataGridViewColumn()
            {
                HeaderText = ((property.GetCustomAttributes(true)[0]) as BindingValueAttribute).Value
            };

            Columns.Add(column);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm. it supposed to be defined as a one of the project components. show up in the ProjectName_Components tab.. your extension inherited from UserControl ?

Comment: @o_O - this question is about extended controls, not user controls.

Comment: My bad, [this might help u](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116311/how-to-put-an-extended-winforms-control-on-toolbox)

Comment: @Z.R.T. - Nope. Where do I see the "Components" tab?

Comment: @o_O - It's fine... The answer you referenced to suggests adding a reference to another assembly using the "Choose Items" option... I do not want that. I want them in the same project. Thanks!

Comment: can you post your  extended DataGridView

Comment: @Z.R.T. - I have added the code.

Comment: This is entirely automatic, the toolbox updates after you compiled your code.  It is an option: Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer > General > "Automatically Populate Toolbox" = True.  Added controls appear at the top of the toolbox.  I did notice that VS2017 got flakey, having to rebuild twice.

Comment: @HansPassant - maybe the problem is that my control is Generic?

Comment: Yes, that is a problem.  The designer is not able to pick a T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class BindedDataGrid : DataGridView
    {
        public BindedDataGrid()
        {
        }

        public BindedDataGrid(Type bindType)
        {
            IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = bindType.GetProperties().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(BindingValueAttribute)));

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                var prop = property.GetCustomAttributes(true)[0];
                if (prop is BindingValueAttribute)
                {
                    var column = new DataGridViewColumn()
                    {
                        HeaderText = property.Name
                    };
                    column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                    Columns.Add(column);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class BindingValueAttribute  : Attribute
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class BindOne
    {
        [BindingValueAttribute()]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BindingValueAttribute()]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

1. first of all make BindedDataGrid none generic
2. create a non parameterized constructor

   ```
       private void InitializeComponent()
   {
       this.bindedDataGrid1 = new PlayingWithThread.BindedDataGrid(typeof(BindOne));
       ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindedDataGrid1)).BeginInit();
   ```