# How do I add a user control to toolbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a CustomControl in toolbox in my C# application

Comment: Possible duplicate, check here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288047/user-controls-not-showing-up-in-the-toolbox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put a UserControl into Visual Studio toolBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446429/how-to-put-a-usercontrol-into-visual-studio-toolbox)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your component is within the project, you can have them automatically added to the toolbox. Go to: Tools -> Options -> Windows Forms Designer and enable the "AutoToolboxPopulate" option.

If it's in a separate solution, you can build the control library, and drag and drop on the toolbox to add the components.

Comment: No matter which of Rowland's options you use make sure to build your control first. It won't show up at the toolbox if it isn't built yet.