# Error when adding user-defined control to a form.

Tags: winforms, designer

I have an user-defined control which includes a property `ElementList` of `IList<WFParament>` type. When I add my control into a form, I get the error:

```
"WorkFlowDesign.WFParament[]" can't be transfered into "WorkFlowDesign.WFParament[]"
```

Comment: Can you show us some code for what WFParament is and maybe some code or additional information on your user control?

Answer (score 0):

Does your usercontrol do anything on load? If so, try wrapping it in:

```
if(!DesignMode)
{
     //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would verify that you don't have two versions of the assembly containing the type WorkFowDesign.WFParament loaded/referenced.  This could happen if your project where you are using the user control references one version of the assembly while the user defined control is compiled against a different version.  If this is the case you will need to update one of the two so that they are referencing the same version of the assembly containing WorkflowDesign.WFParament.